# PyQGIS Temporal Controller current moment

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3, time

I have a QGIS Project with Temporal Controller, in Python Console. How could I capture the current moment of the simulation?

[image]

---

I'm trying, but doesn't work

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
temporal= canvas.temporalController().currentFrameNumber ()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following considering you have QGIS 3.14+

```py
from qgis.PyQt import sip

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
temporalController = canvas.temporalController()
# Cast the QgsTemporalController to QgsTemporalNavigationObject or stucked 
temporalNavigationObject = sip.cast(temporalController, QgsTemporalNavigationObject)


currentFrameNumber = temporalNavigationObject.currentFrameNumber()
print('Frame number', currentFrameNumber)
currentDateTimeRange = temporalNavigationObject.dateTimeRangeForFrameNumber(currentFrameNumber)
print('Current start time range', print(currentDateTimeRange.begin()))
print('Current end time range', print(currentDateTimeRange.end()))

# Experiment section as a reminder (because seems a bug in the signal connect later)
# def animation_state_changed(state):
#     print("DEBUG")

# Signal does not work here when above function + below statement uncommented
# temporalNavigationObject.stateChanged.connect(animation_state_changed)
```

Comment: Did you manage to get the signal to work?

Answer (score 6):

I'm happy to report that this works as desired for me without a sip cast (currently testing on 3.18).

I think the desired signal is the [`updateTemporalRange`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsTemporalController.html#aebe882eb61381033f2de89925d506b32), not the [`stateChanged`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Gps/QgsGpsConnection.html#qgis.core.QgsGpsConnection.stateChanged) signal as mentioned in @ThomasG77's answer (which still fails to connect also in my case).

This prints the current frame number in the QGIS Python console:

```py
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
controller = canvas.temporalController()

def f():
    print(controller.currentFrameNumber())
    
controller.updateTemporalRange.connect(f)
```

Via the frame number, the [`.dateTimeRangeForFrameNumber`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsTemporalNavigationObject.html#ab1fc9a6a282a1435f32d4532f8fba960) can be used to get the datetimes as well.